# Google Maps Search for tourist places

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-places

I'm developing a travel app with meteor.js, I have to recommend tourist places in a given city, I figure out how to give the city location with google autocomplete and geocoding, now I have a problem when I try to find places, I try with the google categories but it only display "common" places in the given city and I need to get representative places inside a given category.

for example:

```
   City: London 
   Categorie: Night Clubs
```

I want to get for examplo a beattles club or something like that.

Is it possible to do that with google places api ?

Thanks

Comment: It's possible, but only with a Places-Search(Autocomplete doesn't support such categories),

Comment: Unfortunately there is no "tourist places" or "historic sites" in the category list.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types

Comment: @Dr.Molle I use the autocomplete only to tell the app whatever city i want then I use common places script search to get the pacles and put them in the map with marks

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, via the `type`-parameter.

According to the [list of supported place-types](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types) you have to use `night_club`